# Installing Xcode 7.x on El Capitan 10.11

Tags: macos, xcode

I am on an old MacBook (mid-2009) that is not supporting Sierra. When I go to the App store to install Xcode 8 (only option available) it says that it is for 10.12 (Sierra) only. That means that if someone has El Capitan only and didn't install Xcode 7 before, cannot start developing apps for macOS / iOS? That seems absurd to me, El Capitan is still a modern OS... I might understand if you are on Leopard, but El Capitan is from 2015!

Is there any way to (legally) bypass this problem?

Comment: if you specifically need a 7.x versions, you could download it from your developer account at apple , specifically at `https://developer.apple.com/download/more/` , where you can scroll the list of available distributions. Once you have the dmg, you can proceed with the installation normally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The last Xcode version compatible with El Capitan is Xcode 8.2.1. If you can't install it from within Apple App Store, visit [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and download the app there. An Apple ID is required.

Xcode is provided as xip file (signed zip). You can simply unzip it by using Archives.app (i.e. with a double-click).